# Split string by ; then compare the values

Tags: java, string, split, compare, java-7

I have a string that returns a bunch of ids seperated by `;`. I am splitting them to get their individual values to pass to another utility to lookup a parent id. I then need to compare the parent ids to each other to make sure all ids are the same value. The string could contain one to many ids.  Example:

```
String unitIdList = "3e46907f-c4e8-44d2-8cab-4abb5a191a72;9d242306-1c7c-4c95-afde-e1057af9d67c;2e96838f-f0df-4c82-b5bc-cb81a6bdb792;b21a4b19-6c1a-4e74-aa84-7900f6ffa7a8"

for ( String unitIds : unitIdList.split(";") ) {
    parentId = UnitUtil.getInstance().getParentId(UUID.fromString(unitIds));

     // now I need to compare parentIds. They should all be the same, but if not then do something else. 
}
```

How can I compare each value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put them all in a `Set` and check that the size is `1`:

```
String unitIdList = // ...
Set<String> distinctIds = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(unitIdList.split(";")));
if(distinctIds.size() == 1) {
    // all the same ids
} else {
    // not all the same!
}
```

Comment: I need to compare each id or each element so does 3e46907f-c4e8-44d2-8cab-4abb5a191a72 EQUAL 9d242306-1c7c-4c95-afde-e1057af9d67c, etc.

Comment: Adding the items to a `Set` automatically removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution:

```
if (Stream.of(unitIdList.split(";")).distinct().count() == 1) {
    // only one distinct ID
} else {
    // more than one distinct IDs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split (like you already have), then loop through each item, comparing to each other item.

```
String unitIdList = "3e46907f-c4e8-44d2-8cab-4abb5a191a72;9d242306-1c7c-4c95-afde-e1057af9d67c;2e96838f-f0df-4c82-b5bc-cb81a6bdb792;b21a4b19-6c1a-4e74-aa84-7900f6ffa7a8";

String[] ids = unitIdList.split(";");

boolean allEqual = true;

for (String s1 : ids) {
    for (String s2 : ids) {
        allEqual = s1.equals(s2);
    }
}

System.out.println("eq: " + allEqual);

if (allEqual) {
    // ...
}
```

This is by no means optimised. As soon as allEqual is false, you can `break` out of both loops.